# Marionette ItemView with pre-existing HTML. Events work if I explicitly define jQuery selector, but not if I go through ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I've got the following ItemView declaration:

```
define([
], function () {
    'use strict';

    var AddComponentDialogView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        el: '#AddComponentDialog',

        //  TODO: I'm reading my HTML from the server so no-op the render method:
        render: function () {

            if (this.onRender) {
                this.onRender();
            }

            return this;
        },

        //  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629207/display-a-view-using-an-existing-rendered-html-with-backbone-marionette
        constructor: function () {

            this._ensureElement();
            this.bindUIElements();

            Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.prototype.constructor.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice(arguments));
        },

        //  TODO: Why can't I reference UI from events? Something about my no-op render hack
        events: {
            'change #RequiredTemplateLookup_ID': 'loadSubcomponents'
        },

        ui: {
            templateLookupId: '#RequiredTemplateLookup_ID',
            subcomponents: '#AddComponentDialog_Subcomponents'
        },

        initialize: function () {
            console.log("this.el:", this.$el.find('#RequiredTemplateLookup_ID'));
        },

        loadSubcomponents: function () {
            console.log("loading subcomponents");
            var templateID = this.ui.templateLookupId.val();
            this.ui.subcomponents.load('AddComponentDialogSubcomponents', { templateID: templateID });
        }

    });

    return AddComponentDialogView;
});
```

The HTML for the element AddComponentDialog is loaded from the server. I then call new view:

```
var addComponentDialogView = new AddComponentDialogView();

//  TODO: Ideally we would would be appending HTML here, but I'm using a no-op version to read from server...
addComponentDialogView.render();
```

At this point everything seems to be up and running. My events work fine if I use the code above, but I swap out `#RequiredTemplateLookup_ID` for `@ui.templateLookupId` I receive an error from jQuery indicating that I'm not working on a valid jQuery selector:

```
uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]
```

Anyone have any ideas how to clean this up?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you're calling `this._ensureElement();` before the parent constructor gets a chance to extend the `events` hash with the custom Marionette behavior.

[`_ensureElement`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-140) calls `setElement`, which delegates the events. Marionette.View needs to [update the `events` hash](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/marionette.view.js#L17) with the `ui` keys before this happens.

I think the constructor should be:

```
    constructor: function () {
        Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.prototype.constructor.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice(arguments));
        this._ensureElement();
        this.bindUIElements();
    },
```

---

*old answer:*

According to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) the `@` symbol will need to be escaped with a double slash `\\` when used in a selector. Does it work if you use `\\@ui.templateLookupId`?

Comment: Naw. I've used it successfully in the past. The @ symbol should get replaced with the actual jQuery selector via Marionette before jQuery even gets to it.

Comment: Oh, right. I was thinking of regular jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 0):

To make marionette fully useable with a pre exisisting element I have used this approach, works with the latest version.

```
var RenderedView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    render: function () {
        this.bindUIElements();

        if (this.onRender) {
            this.onRender();
        }
        return this;
    }
});
```

Moving the `this.bindUIElements()` from the `constuctor` to the `render` method did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked fine in my case:

```
// Itemview
var anItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    ui: {
        removebtn: '.btn-danger'
    },
    events: {
        'click @ui.removebtn': 'showAlert'
    },
    showAlert: function () {
        alert('It works!');
    }
});

// Instantiate view
var viewInstance = new anItemView({
    el: '#test'
});
```

Using the html:

```
<div id="test">This is an itemView.
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</div>
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cardiff/XWUgL/